# count similar rows of one table in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to count same values from one column of the table and return the value and counter, for example: value 1 repeat 3 time, value 2 repeat 2 time, ...

So far my program can store all value of desired column in an array. My problem is I don't know how to compare each value with other value. I know I need a counter and maybe one more array. So I stuck in If condition.

```
try{
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
//Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT N_REGIONKEY FROM NATION " );

List N_REGIONKEY = new ArrayList ();
while (rset.next()){

  N_REGIONKEY.add(rset.getInt("N_REGIONKEY"));
  if (rset.next ==N_REGIONKEY){
           .
           .
           .

   }
  //System.out.println(N_REGIONKEY);
 }
}
```

This is new version of what I wrote with your help, still the answer is not what it should be..

```
try{

  System.out.println("counting rows in NATION table");

  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

//  Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();

  ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT N_REGIONKEY FROM NATION " );

  ArrayList N_REGIONKEY = new ArrayList ();

  while (rset.next()){

      N_REGIONKEY.add(rset.getInt("N_REGIONKEY"));

      int occurrences = 0;  

      for (int i = 0; i<N_REGIONKEY.size();i++)
{    
occurrences = Collections.frequency(N_REGIONKEY,N_REGIONKEY.get(i) );

System.out.println("There is " + occurrences + "occurrences for " + N_REGIONKEY.get(i));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for your helps.Finally, I wrote this program without group by(even-though I know it's much slower). This ones has the same result as with "group by".

```
  try{
```

System.out.println("counting simillar rows in NATION table");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT N_REGIONKEY FROM NATION " );

ArrayList N_REGIONKEY = new ArrayList ();

int[] MyCounter = new int[5];

while (rset.next()){

```
  MyCounter[rset.getInt("N_REGIONKEY")] ++;
```

}

for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){

```
    if (MyCounter[i] > 0) {

        System.out.println("There is " + MyCounter[i] + " ocurrences for " + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int occurrences = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<N_REGIONKEY.size();i++){
occurrences = Collections.frequency(REGIONKEY, REGIONKEY.get(i));
System.out.println("There is " + ocurrences "ocurrences for " + N_RegionKey.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks...The column N_REGIONKEY include numbers from 1 to 4 and some numbers repeated. so what should I put instead of (animals, "bat") ? I've tried (N_REGIONKEY, "i") but the result is 0 occurrences for all values..I think I have to compare each row with entire column, but I don't know how... I already wrote this program with group by..but I would love to compare the performance of this program without group by. I'll appreciate if anyone help me

Comment: didn't you want to know the ocurrences of a particular entry on the list? You can do that by changing animals for the list and "bat" for the entry.

Comment: I exactly want to get the ocurrences of a particular entry on the list(from one column of the table), but still I can't get the reasonable result.The result is not correct..anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to count by sql query, not by array

```
select N_REGIONKEY, count(N_REGIONKEY) as 'COUNT' 
FROM NATION
group by N_REGIONKEY
```

Comment: Thanks..I already wrote this program with group by..but I would love to compare the performance of this program without group by

Comment: Is there any other way than array which I can do this without group by?

Comment: What if table contains billions of rows with same N_REGIONKEY? If you select all this rows, and than try to count them in some array -- this is overkill! Best practice is to do as much as posible on sql side, and get as less as posible data from DB.

Comment: I exactly want to see the result of this program with more sql..I thought that without group by I can do more on sql side...so do you mean if I use "group by", I can shift the program on sql side (rather than server side)?I'll appreciate if you explain more. thanks

Comment: Imagine, that table have 100 rows with N_REGIONKEY=1, and 100 rows with N_REGIONKEY=2. SQL server and app servers connected through network. Network transmit is relatively slow operation. When you use "group by", all calculationf perform on SQL-server, and only result (2 rows) transmited. If you try without "group by", all table must be transmited, this means 200 rows. On small sized tables you will see no diference, but in real world you should use SQL calculations. SQL is not just storage!